# Unexpected token ILLEGAL javascript + php

Tags: php, javascript

Here is the source code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $.post("scan.php?dir=<?=$_POST['dir']?>", function(data){

            alert(data);

        });

    });
```

The generated code is:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $.post("scan.php?dir=C:\xampp\htdocs\windowsMedias\music", function(data){

            alert(data);

        });

    });
```

But it won't work (google chrome returns the error in the title).

If I add the generated code manually, without PHP, it works.

Someone knows how to fix it?

Comment: What debugging have you tried? Did you make sure `$_POST['dir']` actually is the string you posted?

Comment: I'm not sure about what i'm going to say but maybe PHP code in post or get is not parsed as they as just strings

Comment: **You are vulnerable to [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)**. Don't inject external data into HTML documents raw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to urlencode your parameter.

```
$.post("scan.php?dir=<?= urlencode($_POST['dir']) ?>", function(data){
  alert(data);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

The variable you're using contains characters (`:`, `/`, ...), that can not be a part of a URL parameter.

Use [`encodeURI()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) to transform your path into a parameter, that can be passed within a URL:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.post("scan.php?dir=" + encodeURI( "<?=$_POST['dir']?>" ), function(data){

        alert(data);

    });

});
```

Comment: The colon is allowed, but the backslashes need encoding.

Comment: Edited both problems. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with backslashes, you have to json_encode your path like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.post("scan.php?dir=C:\xampp\\htdocs\\windowsMedias\\music", function(data){
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As other answers say, you have to properly encode yourURL parameter. For that, you can use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent):

```
$.post("scan.php?dir=" + encodeURIComponent( "<?=$_POST['dir']?>" ), function(data){
    alert(data);
});
```

What is causing the error are the unencoded backslashes. Your URL contains `\x`, which is a special hexadecimal escape sequence mark. It expects the following two characters to be valid hexadecimal digits (i.e., `[0-9a-fA-F]`), otherwise it will cause an error.